# MySQL Como retornar somente parte do resultado da consulta FULL-TEXT

Tags: php, html, mysql

Digamos que eu tenha esse texto armazenado em uma tabela no meu banco de dados:

> *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
>   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
>   quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
>   consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in **reprehenderit** in voluptate velit esse
>   cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
>   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.*

Se eu consultar a palavra ***reprehenderit***, quero que na minha aplicação, em **PHP/HTML** exiba algo semelhante a isso:

> *... aute irure dolor in **reprehenderit** in voluptate velit esse ...*

Andei lendo sobre a consulta *FULL-TEXT*, mas preciso que retorne as palavras em torno do *termo* da consulta, ao invés do texto todo. Seriam três ou quatro palavras antes e depois do termo consultado.

Como faço?

Comment: Esse tipo de funcionalidade costuma estar no limite do que o suporte a *FULL-TEXT* em databases relacionais consegue fazer de maneira eficiente. Mesmo que você encontre uma solução inteligente para filtrar o texto, em geral recomendo que você comece a pensar em utilizar uma ferramenta própria para indexação e busca como ElasticSearch ou Apache Solr.

Comment: Apenas uma consulta SQL serve? Precisa necessáriamente ser "Palavras" antes e depois? Não pode ser simplesmente um pedaço fixo (pode cortar a primeira/última)?

Comment: @Ismael Pode cortar sim, cara. Eu excluo a primeira e a última já na aplicação. Sem problema. Se quiser formalizar uma resposta com a sua solução, agradeço, mas creio que seja a mesma ideia do Papa Charlie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que encontrei, você pode fazer uma combinação de `LOCATE` e `SUBSTRING` para fazer o corte do texto com base na posição da palavra.

---

> **LOCATE**
>
> The first syntax returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str . The second syntax returns the position of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str , starting at position pos . Returns 0 if substr is not in str . Returns NULL if substr or str is NULL

---

> **SUBSTRING**
>
> The forms without a len argument return a substring from string str starting at position pos . The forms with a len argument return a substring len characters long from string str , starting at position pos . The forms that use FROM are standard SQL syntax. It is also possible to use a negative value for pos . In this case, the beginning of the substring is pos characters from the end of the string, rather than the beginning. A negative value may be used for pos in any of the forms of this function

---

Você pode fazer algo nessa lógica e alterar a quantidade de caracteres para esquerda e para direita a partir da posição da palavra. Usei `+ 10` como exemplo.

```
set @p = (SELECT LOCATE('dolor', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'));
SELECT SUBSTRING( 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' , @p - 10 , @p + 10 );
```

<sub>**output**: `rem ipsum dolor sit ame`</sub>

---

Não recordo se tem alguma função que evite o corte das palavras, como com o `SUBSTRING` que corta `lorem` : `rem`, em todo caso, você pode aumentar o limite e fazer o corte no PHP.

Comment: Com certeza isso resolve. Posso aumentar a quantidade de caracteres, dividir a string em array com base nos espaços e anular o primeiro e último índice, já que seriam poucas palavras. Ajudou bastante! ;)

Comment: Vou procurar algum substituto para `SUBSTRING` e evitar cortar a palavra ao meio, se encontrar faço uma atualização da resposta.